# Does the new star trek universe share the same history as the old one?

Tags: star-trek

It's difficult the get the question correct in the header:

When the whale probe in 2286 reach Earth and they have to travel back in time , will they travel to the past of their universe ?

If yes , than the second part is not necessary to answer.

If No , could they meet the other crew of the enterprise in the past?

Thanks

Comment: I've closed this as a dupe. Several of the answers specifically address the question you've asked.

Comment: What is the answer Yes or No

Comment: Yes. This may also help you; http://trekmovie.com/2008/12/11/bob-orci-explains-how-the-new-star-trek-movie-fits-with-trek-canon-and-real-science/

Comment: @Richard - Do any of the answers to the other question specifically address the question of whether, in the 1986 of the new timeline, it's still true that Kirk & co. from the original timeline appeared (a version of Kirk who grew up with a father, for example) and took two whales along with Dr. Gillian Taylor? It seems to me we don't really know enough about the "temporal mechanics" of the Trek universe to say for sure.

Comment: Also, in the interview you linked to, Orci says he isn't sure about how time travel works in Star Trek IV, saying *'So I would default that it is the science that counts. And say in the case of "Star Trek IV," it could go either way. They cross over to a parallel universe and grab some whales and bring them back and save their own universe.'* I don't think he's even talking about what happens in the Abramsverse here, just about whether in the original STIV, when the crew returned from 1986 back to their time, they were returning to the same future they left or the future of the altered 1986.

Comment: ...And if you go with Orci's speculation that they *did* cross over to a parallel version of 1986 to get the whales, and then returned to future the same timeline they left, that would mean that in that 1986 of *that* timeline there would have been no visitors from the future, and thus presumably there wouldn't be in the 1986 of the Abramsverse either (meaning the answer to Bigben59's question should be "No"). So, I think it's ambiguous, and that this question involves distinct issues from the more general question you marked this as a duplicate of--I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Since he explicitly states that old timelines aren't destroyed, his interview muddies the water **immensely**.

Comment: It's worth noting that asking "Did the original timeline survive" is technically, from the POV of the JJ-verse, asking about the future - the OP here is asking about the past from the standpoint of the JJ-verse. It seems to me the question could be restated as, "If the reboot is in an alternate universe, did it necessarily diverge from the previous universe upon Nero's entry?" Which is a question that can be somewhat begged given the inconsistencies in age between characters, starship technology in the new movies, and so on.