# What happened to the Enterprise crew after TOS?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

I just rewatched the TNG episode "Relics", where Scotty is revealed to have kept himself alive in the transport buffers of a ship. This got me thinking - do we know what happened to other members of the TOS bridge crew after the TOS movies (Up to and including Generations)?

For example, we know that Kirk eventually meets his end in Star Trek: Generations and that Spock has a long career and eventually ends up in the reboot universe.

Do we know any information about other members of the Enterprise crew?

If that question is too broad (for example, if there's lots of canon information about the crew after TOS), then more specifically, what is the latest canon information that we know about their lives?

Comment: McCoy was still alive as of Encounter at Farpoint. I'm not sure Sulu, Chekov, Uhura, Chapel or Rand are mentioned beyond the timeline of the movies (note that Janice Rand is mentioned in the Voyager episode Flashback, but in the timeline of the the sixth movie).

Comment: Just to be clear: do you mean what happened to them after *all* of the movies, i.e. after Generations?

Comment: @Ward That's correct - I'll edit my question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Admiral McCoy** - Confirmed alive as of **2364** (last seen on screen in TNG : "[Encounter at Farpoint](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Encounter_at_Farpoint_%28episode%29)")

[image: Admiral McCoy]

**Captain Sulu** - Confirmed alive as of **2293** (last seen on screen in Voy : [Flashback](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Flashback_%28episode%29))

[image: Captain Sulu]

**Captain James Kirk** - Presumed dead as of **2293** - Later *[confirmed](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Generations)* dead as of **2371** (last seen on screen in "Star Trek: Generations")

[image: Captain Kirk]

**Ambassador Spock** - Confirmed alive as of **2387** (last seen on screen in the rebooted Star Trek continuity)

[image]

**Captain Scott** - Presumed dead as of **2294** - Later confirmed alive as of **2387**. Last canon mention was in the rebooted [Star Trek](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_%28film%29) Continuity

[image]

**Commander Chekov** - Confirmed alive as of **2293**  (last seen on screen in "Star Trek: Generations")

[image]

**Commander Uhura** - Confirmed alive as of **2293** (last seen on screen in [**Star Trek VI**](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_VI:_The_Undiscovered_Country))

[image]

As far as non-canon trek book continuity is concerned, there are vast numbers of stories about the crew of the Enterprise 'post 2293'. Much of it is pretty darned contradictory. For example, in at least ten of the novels Uhura is Captain of the Enterprise, in seven she's an Admiral, two a *Fleet* Admiral, two a Federation Ambassador and in one, the Head of Starfleet Intelligence.

Comment: Chekov was actually last seen in Generations (http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0111280/fullcredits/cast?ref_=m_tt_cl_sc)

Comment: @BrandonDybal - You are, of course correct, Sir.

Comment: Considering Nimoy's recent death (RIP), it will be interesting to note whether *Star Trek Beyond* says that Spock has died!

Comment: In which novels did Uhura command the Enterprise? I'd like to read them!

Comment: Also, has anyone any idea what happened to Janice Rand after she served on the Excelsior?

Comment: @Alexanderjones - Have a quick read through here. You'll be able to find plenty of novel suggestions for Captain Uhura; http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Nyota_Uhura

Answer (score 11):

McCoy was seen on the Enterprise D in the very first episode of TNG.

Scotty, as you said, was trapped inside the USS Jenolan in Relics.

Spock became a Vulcan Ambassador, the only piece of ToS Canon that is definitely still true even in the Abramsverse (regardless of what new Spock becomes)

However, Sulu, Uhura, and Checkov are all unaccounted for as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Spock was a Vulcan Ambassador regardless of the Abrams movies, as established in Unification 1 & 2.

Comment: Spock was an ambassador in the TNG series. Scotty was not trapped inside the Enterprise B, but was trapped inside the USS Jenolan.

Comment: "the only piece of ToS Canon that is definitely still true even in the Abramsverse" - The original timeline still exists; [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10882/33) explains how.

Comment: @neilfein Exists, yes. But for all intents and purposes inaccessible from the Abramsverse.

Comment: Sulu went back in time to the 20th century and became a minor celebrity with a cutting edge sense of humor and a disdain for a certain "Willie Shatner."

Comment: Sulu appeared in one or two of Tuvok's flashbacks during VOY, as a starship captain

Comment: @Izkata To be more specific, the flashbacks were of Tuvok's posting on the *Excelsior*, whose captain was Sulu. This was the ship he was seen commanding in *The Undiscovered Country*.