# In the Star Trek 2009 movie, did they travel back in time or did they travel to an alternate universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009

In the new *Star Trek* movie, did they travel back in time and become their younger selves or are they in an alternate universe like the episode "Mirror, Mirror"?

Comment: not going to post a full answer. But it's an alternate timeline. Only old Spock went back in time and exists along with young spock. This older answer might explain more: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10862/in-star-trek-2009-did-the-original-timeline-survive

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_(film_series)#%22Reboot%22_films)

> This film acts as a reboot to the existing franchise by taking place in an "alternate reality" using the plot device of time travel to depict an altered timeline, featuring younger versions of the original series' cast.

This timeline is called [Kelvin timeline](https://www.geek.com/tech/the-star-trek-movie-timeline-gets-official-name-the-kelvin-timeline-1659663/).

> The Kelvin timeline or alternate reality was a parallel universe created in 2233 with the temporal incursion of the Narada, a Romulan civilian mining vessel under the command of Nero from the year 2387. The alternate reality differed from the primary reality in a number of capacities, including the attack upon the USS Kelvin, the launch of the USS Enterprise in 2258, and the destruction of the planet Vulcan by the Narada. - [memory-beta.wikia.com](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Kelvin_timeline)