# Why didn't Spock save the Romulan Empire by going back in time?

Tags: star-trek, comics, time-travel, star-trek-countdown, idw-comics

In *Star Trek: Countdown* comic series, Spock failed to create Red Matter on time (before the Romulan Empire got destroyed by a Hobus supernova).

Despite Nero's excuses, Spock was a good guy. He accepted Romulus as his home (according to comics). Even Picard and Data (captain of the USS Enterprise of that time) were supporting him to save the Romulan Empire. Why didn't he save the Romulan Empire by going back in time?

When it comes to time travel, Federation had experience with it. Kirk traveled in time by the slingshot effect a number of times (*ST: Voyage Home* and ST:TOS). Picard also returned back to future by reverse tachyon pulse (*ST: First Contact*). So, they were certainly be able to time travel.

Comment: Very strongly related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10421/3267

Comment: @Martin Data was the captain of USS Enterprise of that time.. not Picard. You've moved the bracket to wrong place..

Comment: @JackBNimble You mustn't approve any edit without properly reading that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Temporal Prime Directive](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Temporal_Prime_Directive) clearly states that Starfleet Personal of any kind has not to mess with the timeline.

Given that Spock was his whole life a follower and enforcer of rules and knows very well that altering the timeline can wreak havoc over everything, he most likely didn't even consider that possibility. Because when he goes back in time and saves Romulus, where does he draw the line?

Comment: To save an entire race, I would happily violate the Temporal Prime Directive... Unfortunately, Sachin Shekhar wasn't there for that. :(

Comment: Shouldn't the temporal agents who enforce the Temporal Prime Directive have intervened and prevented the Nerada from changing the timeline?

Comment: @JonathanMiller See [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19183/why-didnt-temporal-agents-stop-nero-from-destroying-vulcan)

Comment: temporal agents were busy with donuts...

Comment: He might've even been stopped by the "temporal police" if he tried to go back in time.

Comment: There are no temporal agents, because Enterprise took place entirely on the Holodeck.

Comment: The Temporal Prime Directive would then apply to Nero, so I don't think that answers this obvious solution to the plot hole.

Comment: @onepound I don't get what you're trying to say. Nero is not bound by Federation rules. Undoing any damage that is done by a time traveler is also done rather regularly by Starfleet personnel. But neither got anything to do with Romulus going poof.

Comment: @Bobby yes I agree I misread the question. I've deleted the comment.